# How to create a True or False function that sees if an image is in another image using cv2

Tags: python, templates, matching, opencv

I want to make a program that checks if an image is in another image in Python using cv2.

I have tried template matching but have seen that it still works/templates even if the image is not in the other image.

So it would just draw a template in a random place.

Is there a way to see if an image is in another image and if there is return True and if there is not return False.

I would like to use cv2 but if another module works that's fine too.

Comment: use a try except and return false in case of a failure (i.e return false from except)

Comment: Thank you for your response but i guess i did not make my question clear. My test program works even if the image is not there. In my case im using Valorant and im looking for the triple, quadruple, or ace icon on the top right. So here is a picture of what it is supposed to look like. https://gyazo.com/92a216d7fc99e8c98cc348e832a9baa2. But it looks like https://gyazo.com/2783746e0a4c00d564eb34ea6f6f8cda. Basically program still outlines even though image is not there. Any ideas to fix this?